# what is the easiest way of getting a number from a url?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am hoping someone can help me, I have created url's like this

```
/this/is/a/test/index.asp
/this/is/a/test/index-1.asp
/this/is/a/test/index-2.asp
/this/is/a/test/index-3.asp
```

What is the easiest way to strip the number from the URL?

Instead of using variables like this:

```
/this/is/a/test/index.asp?no=1
/this/is/a/test/index.asp?no=2
/this/is/a/test/index.asp?no=3
```

to create variables I am using the number in the URL to dynamically call the content on the page.

If the url is: `/this/is/a/test/index-3.asp` it should use the 3 and match the content according to it, similar as if I were to call

> ?no=3

I am using PHP for this...

The url structure will always have the variable define as match the last '-' [the-number] '.asp'

Thanks

Gerald Ferreira

Comment: The GET-parameter is part of the URL. So why do you want to do it?

Comment: Hi Halfdan, because if google hits my page 'index-1.asp' then it will show the content as the same as on index.asp although it is actually different. if I am right you will need to follow the links to get the url to pass the values. I am creating clean url's but already using htaccess - and it will not be able to help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to match it out with:

```
if (preg_match('/\-(\d+)\.asp$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $a)) {
    $pageNumber = $a[1];
} else {
    // failed to match number from URL
}
```

Comment: Nice one, Thanks James exactly what I were looking for... Can you maybe tell me what the 'd' meand in the regex

Comment: @Gerald: The `\d` is an abbreviation for decimals.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to map URL patterns to actual URLs.  You could achieve what you want with something similar to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^index-([0-9]+).asp$ index.asp?no=$1
```

Comment: Hi Nick - I am already using mod_rewrite to construct the pages, I don't think I will be able to use it for this particilar case.

Comment: Hi Nick - maybe just to abreviate a bit. I should have mentioned it in the question above, but the index is not necessary a constant. Therefore I cannot really use it, because it vary to much, and will likely clash with the rewrite rules that I already have