# How to get a Specific number from an url in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following url : `http://example.com/category/post-is-783476?src=mainPage`. With the pattern How to get the numbers(78346) from the url ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get number from an url in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886584/get-number-from-an-url-in-php)

Comment: Try with `/(\d+)/g`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the easiest way of getting a number from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696628/what-is-the-easiest-way-of-getting-a-number-from-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<?php
$input_line = "http://example.com/category/post-is-783476?src=mainPage";
preg_match("/([0-9]+)\/?/", $input_line, $output_array);
echo $output_array[1];
?>
```

Output: 783476

Comment: But Sir '**Post-is**' is Different for each url.

Comment: @Milon this should work for every id.

Comment: I mean The Url is different for every url like  http://example.com/category/hello-world-673534?src=mainPage, I just want the numbers from url dynamically.

Comment: @Milon updated my answer

Comment: `\/?` is totally useless.

Comment: Without regex you can also do that: `$result = array_pop(explode('-' ,parse_url($input_line, PHP_URL_PATH)));`